# asp:ListBox control selecting a row using javascript

Tags: javascript, .net-3.5, listbox-control

I have an asp:ListBox control on my web page.  I am trying to select an item in the list using javascript.  After looking at the underlying structure I have tried:

```
catListBoxCtl[0].Selected = true;
```

Which does indeed set the 'selected' value to true but it doesn't highlight the appropriate row.  I am just trying to replicate what a user does when you select a row using a mouse.  How do you select a row programatically so that it get's highlighted etc?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're missing the reference to the options. Try:

```
catLIstBoxCtl.options[0].selected = true;
```

Comment: Thanks, for some reason my intellisense wasn't show 'options' as an option, eventually I did try it and it worked.

Comment: Intellisense: I use it and love it, but don't let it become intellicrutch.